# What's the difference between Author or Writer?

Tags: differences

What's the difference, if any, between the noun **author** and **writer**

Comment: I saw that question earlier, I don't think it's a duplicate as they are asking about the verbs and I am asking about the nouns. Plus there's an excellent answer already.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially none. In some countries "author" is used as the legal creator of the work for copyright purposes